# How can I add functionality to a 3rd party iOS library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

There's a cocoapods calendar library I'm using that I want to add some functionality/change the behavior for a couple minor things. What's the preferred way to do this?

Can I define a child class that overrides the functionality? I assume that changing the code in the Pod's source is not the way to do it - what is?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a question for stackoverflow. It should really be posted to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. I give my answer anyways.

First and foremost, you have to follow the license. Most open source allows you to make changes as long as you commit those changes back to the project. If you think that what you are doing will be valuable to the community, you should start contributing.

Other than modifying the source, you should be able to use it any way you need. Subclass to extend. Add categories to augment. Embed in your own classes to manage.

All you really need to do is follow the license. Usually this means attribution and contributing modifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding completely new functionality to the library and not overriding functionality it provides, I suggest creating a category.

Comment: I need to override private functionality, which also calls other private methods. Any suggestions?